# Create ID using current DATE with additional auto increment number

Tags: javascript, oracle, asp-classic

I faced a problem in generating ID for my form. I'm currently using ASP Classic and Oracle.
I need to create ID that has current date and 2 additional numbers
eg: `yyyymmdd`+auto increment number in sequence order (2015031601, 2015031602).

Until now, I only able to return current date value in my form with random numbers which created using `Math.random()` function in Javascript. But, the ID actually needs to have the auto increment number in sequence.

Code for the current date and math random for random number:

```
    var date = new Date();
    var todaydate= date.getDate();
    var todaymon= date.getMonth()+1;
    var todayyear= date.getFullYear();
    var q=todayyear; 
    if(todaymon<=9)
    {
        var y= "0"+todaymon;
    }
    else
        var y= todaymon;

    if(todaydate<=9)
    {
        var z="0"+todaydate;
    }
    else
        var z=todaydate; 

    var k = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 01);
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    document.getElementById('ID').value = q+y+z+k;
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you expect the sequence number to come from? You would have to store it someone to keep going back to it and incrementing it, preferably in your database. At the moment I'm not sure how what you have posted even attempts to do that?

Comment: Is the sequence supposed to start from 1 each day?

Comment: @DavidFaber Not sure where this is coming from, did the OP state it resets after a day? Not just you notice pavel-gatnar has [mentioned this as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079836/create-id-using-current-date-with-additional-auto-increment-number#comment46393694_29080232).

Comment: Depending on what you want to use this for, from a security perspective it's not a very good solution if the ID increments. Even with the date stamp in front of it you can guess the next value too easily. If this isn't a concern that's fine. However if you explain what it is you are trying to accomplish we may be able to provide an alternative solution.

Comment: @Lankymart, the OP mentions "2 additional numbers" ... an actual sequence in Oracle would exceed two digits in a hurry. Also there's no reason to include the date as part of the ID if the sequence doesn't start over each day.

Comment: @DavidFaber Good point I'd missed that. Still unsure as to why they want to do that, if the question was more complete we might all be able to provide better solutions.

Comment: @Lankymart, agreed. Hopefully the OP will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

create ORACLE sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_name_seq;
```

and provide the id in a BEFORE INSERT trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER table_name_BRI ON table_name
BEFORE INSERT
FOR EACH ROW IS
BEGIN
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') || table_name_seq.NEXTVAL)
  INTO :NEW.id
  FROM dual;
END;
```

Comment: if you want the sequence to start from 1 each day, you have to create a table with daily counters and use it instead of the sequence